# Binary Matrix Multiplication with OR Instead of Sum

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to determine how to perform binary matrix multiplication in Python / Numpy / Scipy where instead of plus (addition), OR is used, meaning when we "multiply" the two matrices below

```
1  0
1  1
0  1

1  1  0
0  1  1
```

we should get

```
[[1., 1., 0],
[1., 1., 1.],
[0, 1., 1.]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but could you just multiply the two matrices normally and set any non zero elements in the result to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> a = np.matrix([[1,1,0],[0,1,1]], dtype=bool)
> a.T * a 
matrix([[ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Normal numpy arrays have access to matrix-style multiplication via the `dot` function.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific data in the problem

```
a = np.array([[1,  0],
               [1,  1],
               [0,  1]], dtype=bool)
b = np.array([[1,  1,  0],
               [0,  1,  1]], dtype=bool)

print np.dot(a,b)
```

to see 0's and 1's simply multiply with 1

```
print 1*np.dot(a,b)
```

Answer is

```
[[1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [0 1 1]]
```